# Bind to total of an items field in an ObservableCollection and update when values change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection that populates a datagrid in WPF. I need to bind to the total of the "Hours" column, and have that total update when a value in the "Hours" column is changed. I can achieve this by listening to the "LostFocus" event and running a function, but would like to try my hand at binding.

The issue I am running into, is the NotifyPropertyChanged event will not fire when an items property in the collection is changed.

The sortie class NotifyPropertyChanged will fire, but the collection doesn't interpret that as its own property changing. How can I listen to the sortie PropertyChanged from the collection in the missions class?

My Models

```
public class Mission : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Sortie> sorties;
    public ObservableCollection<Sortie> Sorties
    {            
        get { return this.sorties; }
        set
        {

            if (this.sorties != value)
            {
                this.sorties = value;                   
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Sorties");   
            }
        }  
    } 
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
} 

public class Sortie : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double hours;
    public double Hours
    {
         get {return this.hours;}
         set
         {
            if (this.hours != value)
            {
                this.hours = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Hours");
            }
         }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't bother posting my XAML or View Model, as I am confident I can solve the issue once I learn how to trigger a PropertyChanged event for the collection and I wanted to spare you having to read through massive amounts of code. If you believe it is needed however, let me know.

Comment: Multidupe.  OC doesn't listen to INPC of its children.  You have to manage this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a readonly property in the parent viewmodel that calculates the value.

```
public double SortieHours => Sorties.Sum(x => x.Hours);
```

Parent viewmodel handles `PropertyChanged` on each item in `Sorties`, and `CollectionChanged` on `Sorties`. In `CollectionChanged` on `Sorties`, you have to add/remove `PropertyChanged` handlers from `Sortie` instances as they're added and removed. When you get a new `Sorties` collection (you might want to make that setter private for this reason), you need to toss out all the old handlers and add new ones.

Now, whenever a `Sortie` is added or removed, or its `Hours` changes, or somebody hands you a new `Sorties` collection, raise `PropertyChanged`:

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SortieHours));
```

And bind that property to whatever you like in the XAML.

This looks horrible (because it is), but what else are you going to do?

A lot of people would advise you to give `Sortie` an `HoursChanged` event. `PropertyChanged` is annoying for this type of case because it can get raised for multiple different properties and you have to check which one. And it's a magic string thing.

Above is C#6. For C#5,

```
public double SortieHours { get { return Sorties.Sum(x => x.Hours); } }

OnPropertyChanged("SortieHours");
```

Comment: not sure why this is considered ugly, seems rational to me.  +1

Comment: @NappingRabbit It’s ugly because there are so many events and handlers involved in keeping a single value up to date. It’s rational, certainly: It’s your only option, and it works. But it’s not pretty.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/694370/How-to-Listen-to-Property-Chang) to be a big help.  It creates a base class for ObservableCollections to "AutoMagicly" add the PropertyChanged events of the collection items to the CollectionChanged event.